# SQL Rename row result

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SellThruDaily852] WHERE RetailerID='AMAZON' --order by StartDate
        AND StartDate in (20170731,20170801,20170802,20170803,20170804,20170805,20170806);
WITH AMAZON AS
    (
    SELECT 
        MAX(ProcessRunId) ProccessID,
        DATEPART(YY,DATEADD(DD,-1,CAST(CreatedDate AS DATE))) VizioYear , 
        DATEPART(WK,DATEADD(DD,-1,CAST(CreatedDate AS DATE))) WeekID,
        CAST(DATENAME(dw,CAST(CreatedDate AS DATE)) AS VARCHAR) DayName,
        FileName,
        CAST(CreatedDate AS DATE) CreateDate
        --CreatedDate
    FROM [dbo].[FileCheckResult]
    WHERE
        RetailerID='AMAZON' 
        AND FileCheckType='Received' 
        AND FileDataType='SellThru' 
        AND FileName like '852_AMAZON_9%'
    GROUP BY FileName,CAST(CreatedDate AS DATE)
    )
SELECT 
    * 
FROM AMAZON
WHERE 
    VizioYear=2017 
    AND WeekID=31
ORDER BY CreateDate
```

And this is the result:

[image]

what I would like to do is change the first two rows in DayName to - Monday and Tuesday.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
--YOUR PREVIOUS CODE--
--AFTER CTE
SELECT 
        ProccessID,
        VizioYear , 
        WeekID,
        CASE WHEN rownumber in (1,2) THEN 'Monday and Tuesday' ELSE DayName END AS DayName ,
        FileName,
        CreateDate
FROM
(
SELECT 
    *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY CreateDate)  as rownumber
FROM AMAZON
WHERE 
    VizioYear=2017 
    AND WeekID=31
) as ABC
ORDER BY ABC.CreateDate
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is that you have 3 files for a single date and it of course returns the same DayName (DATENAME(Date)).

The ideal solution would the to UPDATE THE CreateDate from 2017-08-02 to 2017-07-31 2017-08-01 for the two rows you highlighted and this way you will get the desired result.

If you cannot modify the data and want to do it in the query, you can add a single CASE to get the results you want:

```
CASE 
WHEN FileName == 'FileMonday.csv' THEN 'Monday'
WHEN FileName == 'FileTuesday.csv' THEN 'Tuesday'
ELSE   
CAST(DATENAME(dw,CAST(CreatedDate AS DATE)) AS VARCHAR) 
END AS DayName,
```